# How can I add more than 2 conditions to the LlNQ where clause?

Tags: linq

I have a *LINQ* query with more than 2 where conditions, but it doesn't seem to evaluate with more than 2 conditions. Is there a way to add more conditions to the where clause?

```
var query = 
   from f in XElement.Load(MapPath("flightdata3.xml")).Elements("flight")
   where (string)f.Element("departurelocation") == From && 
         (string)f.Element("destinationlocation") == DestCity &&
         (string)f.Element("airline") == Airline
         // && (string)f.Element("departuredate") == DepartDate && 
         // (string)f.Element("departuretime")==DepartTime
         //&& (string)f.Element("returndate")==ReturnDate && 
         //(string)f.Element("returntime")==ReturnTime
   orderby Convert.ToInt32(f.Element("price").Value)
   select new
   {
      FlightNumber = (Int32)f.Element("flightnumber"),
      Airline = (string)f.Element("airline"),
      Departure = (string)f.Element("departureairportsymbol"),
      DepartTime = (string)f.Element("departuretime"),
      Destination = (string)f.Element("destinationairportsymbol"),
      ArrivalTime = (string)f.Element("arrivaltime"),
      Stops = (int)f.Element("numberofstops"),
      Duration = (string)f.Element("duration"),
      Cabin = (string)f.Element("cabin"),
      Price = "$" + (Int32)f.Element("price"),
      ImagePath = (string)f.Element("airlineimageurl").Value
   };
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: The code, the code. Show us the code.

Comment: an example would allow us to help you

Comment: I added the code to the original post.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't seem to evaluate ??

Comment: Need the XML as well to see where the problem is, you can have as many conditions in a where clause as you want, most likely you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: I checked my XML file with w3schools xml validator and there were no errors found.

Comment: @multiv123 it's about the mapping from your xml used in the linq to xml statement - something most likely doesn't match up - that's why you have to show both.

Comment: I looked at the XML and the format of the response from the web form, and yes, they did not match. I should be okay now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ absolutely allows more than two WHERE conditions. Have you tried separating the query into more manageable pieces? LINQ uses deferred execution anyway so you won't see a performance penalty in doing so.

You should also consider making a class to hold the information you're stuffing into the result.

```
public class FlightDetail
{
    public Int32 FlightNumber { get; set; }

    public String Airline { get; set; }

    public String Departure { get; set; }

    public String DepartureTime { get; set; }

    public String Destination { get; set; }

    public String ArrivalTime { get; set; }

    public Int32 Stops { get; set; }

    public String Duration { get; set; }

    public String Cabin { get; set; }

    public Int32 Price { get; set; }

    public String ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

Then something like this which is more readable but should also help you find whatever bug is popping up.

```
var flights = 
   from f in XElement.Load(MapPath("flightdata3.xml")).Elements("flight")
   select new FlightDetail
   {
      FlightNumber = (Int32)f.Element("flightnumber"),
      Airline = (string)f.Element("airline"),
      Departure = (string)f.Element("departureairportsymbol"),
      DepartTime = (string)f.Element("departuretime"),
      Destination = (string)f.Element("destinationairportsymbol"),
      ArrivalTime = (string)f.Element("arrivaltime"),
      Stops = (int)f.Element("numberofstops"),
      Duration = (string)f.Element("duration"),
      Cabin = (string)f.Element("cabin"),
      Price = "$" + (Int32)f.Element("price"),
      ImagePath = (string)f.Element("airlineimageurl").Value
   };

var flightsByLocation = 
   flights.
   where (string)f.Element("departurelocation") == From && 
         (string)f.Element("destinationlocation") == DestCity
   select new FlightDetail
   {
      FlightNumber = (Int32)f.Element("flightnumber"),
      Airline = (string)f.Element("airline"),
      Departure = (string)f.Element("departureairportsymbol"),
      DepartTime = (string)f.Element("departuretime"),
      Destination = (string)f.Element("destinationairportsymbol"),
      ArrivalTime = (string)f.Element("arrivaltime"),
      Stops = (int)f.Element("numberofstops"),
      Duration = (string)f.Element("duration"),
      Cabin = (string)f.Element("cabin"),
      Price = "$" + (Int32)f.Element("price"),
      ImagePath = (string)f.Element("airlineimageurl").Value
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be an issue with having more then one condition. For example, you could have something like this from an Order table.

```
var orderDetails = (from o in context.OrderDetails
where o.OrderID == orderID
where o.OrderName == orderName
select o).ToList();
```

Comment: multiv123 wants an answer for more than 2 conditions.